# How were the first engineering licenses issued?

Tags: engineering-history, licensure

One of the criteria for getting an engineering license is working under a licensed engineer for a period of time. This seems like a chicken-and-egg problem. How were the first engineering licenses issued?

Comment: Please specify a jurisdiction. PEs have only been a thing in the US for about 100 years and legislation to establish them exists at the state level. These laws have been amended many, many times over the years and would have had different requirements for the initial roll out...

Comment: ...but I think you may simply be misunderstanding the distinction between the "qualifying experience" requirement and the most common route to satisfying that requirement (i.e., working under another PE).

Comment: It used to be that certain people who worked in the field of engineering could be "grandfathered" as P.E.s if they got existing P.E.s to endorse their application to the state licensing board.  These potential candidates would have to demonstrate that they had a certain number of years of experience in addition to the endorsements of other P.E.s.  The "grandfather" route is no longer available, and AFAIK, all P.E. candidates must attend an accredited engineering school and take the EIT and FE exams to becomes licensed.

Comment: In the U.S., the first  engineering licensure law was enacted in Wyoming in 1907.  This article outlines some significant milestones in licensure since then: https://www.nspe.org/resources/press-room/resources/100-years-engineering-licensure

Comment: In the UK, the various Engineering Institutes (Mechanical, Electrical, etc) were originally learned societies. A group of like minded people (usually the leading figures in the industry) got together to found the society, write its rule-book, and appoint its first officers. New members would be proposed and seconded by existing members and approved or rejected by a vote, just like any other "private member's club". Setting up the modern system of "chartered engineers" (roughly equivalent to the USA PEs) happened much later, after the organizations had already existed for 100 years or more.